# Pointing to ModelView in View from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

In Following code I'm getting error as:

**Cannot create an instance of "MainViewModels"** ... also, always DataContext is marked 
with red lines. Any help is appreciated.

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleMvvmUsingWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleMvvmUsingWPF"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MainViewModels x:Key="MainViewModels" />
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="First Name:" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Width="100" Text="{Binding ModelPerson.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock  Text="Last Name:" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Width="100" Text="{Binding ModelPerson.LastName}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock  Text="Update Date:" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Width="100" Text="{Binding ModelPerson.UpdatedDate}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Width="100"/>

    </Grid>


</Window>
```

Comment: `x:Key` and `DataContext` are mismatched (MainViewModels / MainViewModel)

Comment: @dbaseman I had a missing 's' at the end of DataContext but fixed now. Yet I'm getting the error.

Comment: dbaseman is right about that, however, the error you point out in your question seems to be in the class MainViewModels. Since you didn't include the code for that class it is hard to tell what is causing the error.

Comment: Solution: The problem was due to using wrong argument in INotifyPropertyChanged interface. I was passing a wrong argument to OnPropertyChanged() method.  Thanks to all for helping.

Comment: @amitkohan ideally either post your answer, or flag so that a mod can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to using wrong argument in *`INotifyPropertyChanged`* interface implementation. I was passing a wrong argument to *`OnPropertyChanged()`* method.